# Active Record Validations, presence of not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation

I'm working on a form to create new users for a `Ruby on Rails` project. I'd like to start by mentioning that the form itself works just fine when filled out correctly and creates users exactly the right way. However, not all of the `Active Record Validation` appears to be working, in particular the `validates :institution_pid, presence: true` bit. The rest of the form works the way it should. If an element is blank or filled out in correctly an error message pops up on the screen so the user can fix it and the form won't submit. But if the form is submitted without an institution being chosen, instead of that error showing up it submits anyways and then I get this error:

```
ActiveFedora::ObjectNotFoundError in UsersController#create
```

This is happening, obviously, because it's trying to use the institution from the form that hasn't been filled out. What I can't figure out is why it's doing that, and submitting, instead of the validation popping up an error because the form hasn't been filled out correctly.

Here is my User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Connects this user object to Hydra behaviors. 
  include Hydra::User

  # Connects this user object to Blacklights Bookmarks. 
  include Blacklight::User
  include Aptrust::SolrHelper

  # Connects this user object to Role-management behaviors. 
  include Hydra::RoleManagement::UserRoles

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :database_authenticatable,
  # :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :timeoutable,     :validatable

  validates :email, :phone_number, :role_ids, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :institution_pid, presence: true
  validate :institution_pid_points_at_institution

  # Custom format validations.  See app/validators
  validates :name, person_name_format: true, if: ->{ name.present? }
  validates :email, email: true

  # Handle and normalize phone numbers
  phony_normalize :phone_number, :default_country_code => 'US'

  validates :phone_number, :phony_plausible => true

  # This method assigns permission groups
  def groups
    super + institution_groups
  end

  def institution_groups
    if institutional_admin?
      ["Admin_At_#{institution_group_suffix}"]
    elsif institutional_user?
      ["User_At_#{institution_group_suffix}"]
    else
      []
    end
  end

  # Blacklight uses #to_s on youruser class to get a user-displayable 
  # login/identifier for the account. 
  #
  # Method modified from the Blacklight default.
  def to_s
    name || email
  end

  def as_json(options = nil)
    json_data = super
    json_data.delete('api_secret_key')
    json_data.delete('encrypted_api_secret_key')
    json_data
  end

  # Roles are managed through the hydra-role-management gem.
  def is?(role)
    self.roles.pluck(:name).include?(role.to_s)
  end

  def admin?
    is? 'admin'
  end

  def institutional_admin?
    is? 'institutional_admin'
  end

  def institutional_user?
    is? 'institutional_user'
  end

  def role_id
    if(admin?)
      Role.where(name: 'admin').first_or_create.id
    elsif(institutional_admin?)
      Role.where(name: 'institutional_admin').first_or_create.id
    elsif(institutional_user?)
      Role.where(name: 'institutional_user').first_or_create.id
    end
  end

  # Since an Institution is an ActiveFedora Object, these two objects cannot be related as normal (i.e. belongs_to)
  # They will be connected through the User.institution_pid.
  def institution
    @institution ||= Institution.find(self.institution_pid)
  rescue ActiveFedora::ObjectNotFoundError => e
    logger.warn "#{self.institution_pid} is set as the institution for #{self}, but it doesn't exist"
    @institution = NilInstitution.new
  end

  def institution_group_suffix
    clean_for_solr(institution_pid)
  end

  # Guest users are disabled in this application.  The default Blacklight installation includes the gem devise-guests
  # which is not bundled with this app.  hydra-role-management gem requires a guest boolean, so we must provide it here.
  # This will be fixed in hydra-role-management 0.1.1
  def guest?
    false
  end

  attr_reader :api_secret_key

  def api_secret_key=(key)
    @api_secret_key = key
    self.encrypted_api_secret_key = if key.blank?
      nil
    else
       password_digest(key)
    end
  end

  # Generate a new API key for this user
  def generate_api_key(length = 20)
    self.api_secret_key = SecureRandom.hex(length)
  end

  # Verifies whether an API key (from sign in) matches the user's API key.
  def valid_api_key?(input_key)
    return false if encrypted_api_secret_key.blank?
    bcrypt  = ::BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_api_secret_key)
    key = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("#{input_key}#{User.pepper}", bcrypt.salt)
    Devise.secure_compare(key, encrypted_api_secret_key)
  end

  class NilInstitution
    def name
      "Deleted Institution"
    end

    def to_param
      'deleted'
    end

    def brief_name
      "Deleted Institution"
    end

    def users
      []
    end

    def intellectual_objects
      []
    end

    def bytes_by_format
      {}
    end
  end

  private

  def institution_pid_points_at_institution
    errors.add(:institution_pid, "is not a valid institution") unless Institution.exists?(institution_pid)
  end

end
```

This is my Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  inherit_resources
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def destroy
    name = @user.to_s
    destroy!(notice: "User #{@user.to_s} was deleted.")
  end

  def edit_password
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update_password
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully changed password."
    else
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:alert] = "Current password was incorrect, new password was too short, or passwords did not match. Password has not been changed."
    end
  end

  def generate_api_key
    @user.generate_api_key

    if @user.save
      msg = ["Please record this key.  If you lose it, you will have to generate a new key.",
         "Your API secret key is: #{@user.api_secret_key}"]
      msg = msg.join("<br/>").html_safe
      flash[:notice] = msg
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'ERROR: Unable to create API key.'
    end

    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  private

    def build_resource_params
      [params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:name, :email, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation).tap do |p|
        p[:institution_pid] = build_institution_pid if params[:user][:institution_pid]
        p[:role_ids] = build_role_ids if params[:user][:role_ids]
      end]
    end

    def build_institution_pid
      institution = Institution.find(params[:user][:institution_pid])
      authorize!(:add_user, institution)
      institution.id
    end

    def build_role_ids
      [].tap do |role_ids|
        unless params[:user][:role_ids].empty?
          roles = Role.find(params[:user][:role_ids])

            authorize!(:add_user, roles)
            role_ids << roles.id

        end
      end
    end

  def user_params
    params.required(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end

end
```

This is the code for the form I'm using:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Registering New User</h1>
</div>

<%= simple_form_for(@user, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :name, autofocus: true %>
      <%= f.input :email %>
      <%= f.input :phone_number %>

      <%= f.input :institution_pid, collection: institutions_for_select, as: :select, label: "Institution" %>

      <%= f.association :roles, collection: roles_for_select, as: :radio_buttons %>

      <%= f.input :password %>
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn doc-action-btn btn-success") do %>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> Submit
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to @user, {class: "btn doc-action-btn btn-cancel"} do %>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Cancel
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is the HTML generated by the form for the institution element, the one giving me trouble, in case that helps.

```
<div class="controls">
  <select class="select required" id="user_institution_pid" name="user[institution_pid]">
    <option value=""></option>  
    <option value="aptrust-dev:363">APTrust</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="aptrust-dev:365">North Carolina State University</option>
    <option value="aptrust-dev:364">Columbia University</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Log:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-28 09:05:15 -0500
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"WjALLu82iJDDNBEnNpdqupVERdYVOg1l1W/t5v7yaog=", "user"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"", "phone_number"=>"", "institution_pid"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Unpermitted parameters: institution_pid
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActiveFedora::ObjectNotFoundError (Unable to find "" in fedora. ):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:52:in `build_institution_pid'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:46:in `block in build_resource_params'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:45:in `tap'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:45:in `build_resource_params'


  Rendered /Users/kec6en/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@fluctus/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/kec6en/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@fluctus/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/kec6en/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@fluctus/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/kec6en/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@fluctus/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (22.0ms)
```

Comment: Where is `create` method in UsersController?

Comment: Also, can you share the server log when you submit the form.

Comment: You can chat with me http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Comment: I don't have the reputation to be in the chat room actually. I posted the log and there isn't a `create` method in the UsersController. I'm kind of new to Rails so I'm not sure why there isn't one. I think we're inheriting it from somewhere. I'm sorry I'm not more helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks for looking over my code anyways. I needed to add a line that checks if the parameter is empty in the `build_institution_pid` method. Now everything validates the way it should.

Answer (score 0):

this is what makes your code fail.

`Unpermitted parameters: institution_pid`

do
`params.require(:user).permit(:institution_pid)`

or s.th. like this.

see more
http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html